# How do I initialize a Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, initialization, uint8array

I want to create a Uint8Array with 8 elements.  I tried this

```
var myarr = new Uint8Array(255,255,255,255,40,92,143,2);
```

but when I run

```
myarr.length
```

I get back "255" when I expect the answer would be "8".  I assume I'm doing somethign wrong in my intitialization step but don't know what that is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The different constructors are:

```
new TypedArray(); // new in ES2017
new TypedArray(length);
new TypedArray(typedArray);
new TypedArray(object);
```

So when you do

```
new Uint8Array(255)
```

It will take it as a length. However you can pass an object (an array) instead which will be iterated to create the uint array:

```
new Uint8Array([255, 255, /*..*/]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add brackets to the list inside the Uint8Array argument

`let myarr = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,...])`

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a `UintArray` with a regular array like this:

```js
const arr = [255,255,255,255,40,92,143,2]
const uintarr = new Uint8Array(arr)
console.log(uintarr.length)
```